# LINQ - Assign a Value to Anonymous Type's Read Only Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, anonymous-types

I would like to create an anonymous type from linq. Then change the value of a single property(status) manually and give the list to a repeater as data source. But doesn't let me do that as theay are read-only. Any suggestion?

```
 var list = from c in db.Mesai
                   join s in db.MesaiTip on c.mesaiTipID equals s.ID
                   where c.iseAlimID == iseAlimID
                   select new
                   {
                       tarih = c.mesaiTarih,
                       mesaiTip = s.ad,
                       mesaiBaslangic = c.mesaiBaslangic,
                       mesaiBitis = c.mesaiBitis,
                       sure = c.sure,
                       condition = c.onaylandiMi,
                       status = c.status
                   };
 foreach (var item in list)
 {
     if (item.condition==null)
     {
          item.status == "Not Confirmed";
     }
 }
 rpCalisanMesai.DataSource = list.ToList();
 rpCalisanMesai.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the value after creating the list, just set the right value *while* creating the list.

```
var list = from c in db.Mesai
               join s in db.MesaiTip on c.mesaiTipID equals s.ID
               where c.iseAlimID == iseAlimID
               select new
               {
                   tarih = c.mesaiTarih,
                   mesaiTip = s.ad,
                   mesaiBaslangic = c.mesaiBaslangic,
                   mesaiBitis = c.mesaiBitis,
                   sure = c.sure,
                   condition = c.onaylandiMi,
                   status = c.onaylandiMi != null ? c.status : "Not Confirmed"
               };
```

Also, if you could change the property, your problem would be executing the query *twice*: first in the `foreach`-loop, and then *again* by calling `list.ToList()` (which would create new instances of the anonymous type).

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks! One more thing I suppose doddle for you. First line in the anonymous object tarih=c.mesaiTarih, which is date. I am not able to change it to Shortdate format. Pls help!

Comment: @Jude What does "not able to change it" mean exactly? Better ask a new question to provide more context. It's hard to answer questions in comments.

Comment: OK. I just meant I had an error like: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method.

Comment: That's because you're running you're query against a database, so it get's translated to a SQL query. But, as the error message tells you, `ToShortDateString` can't be converted to a SQL statement (you'll find *a lot* of questions about this topic on SO). I don't know the rest of your code or your usecase, but I think it would be best if you just stick with `DateTime`, and only format the value in your front-end (if possible).

Comment: Sometimes you need to do things in two stages, do what you can in the DB, produces an anonymous object, then AsEnumerable and select on that to do any work that has to be done in memory and create a second object.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot, anonymous type's properties are read-only.

You need to set it during object creation. See @Dominic answer for code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can. For instance:

```
var data = (from a in db.Mesai select new { ... status = new List<string>() .. }).ToList();
```

Next, compute your status:

```
foreach (var item in data) {
    item.status.Add("My computed status");
}
```

And then on rendering:

```
foreach (var item data) {
    Response.Write(item.status[0]);
}
```

EDIT: The list can even be intialized as per your requirement:

```
var data = (from a in db.Mesai select new { ... status = new List<string>(new 
string[] { c.status }) .. }).ToList();
foreach (var item in data) {
    item.status[0] = "My computed status";
}
```

EDIT2: Seems like you *must* initialize the list, preferably with e.g. c.rowid.ToString(), otherwise the optimizer assigns the same new List() to all items, thinking that this might be some game or something.